# Why was the length of img tag which has height 100% be shrunken in nested flex box?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a trouble about flex item in css.

Please see the folloing code in jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/mitsuru793/n0y6g5qu/32

html

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
  <div class="main-flex-container">
    <div class="text">text</div>
    <div class="image-flex-container">
      <div class="label">label</div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x400/ff0000/ffffff">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

scss

```
.main {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;

  color: white;
}

.main-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  .text {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: orange;
  }
}

.image-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  .label {
    background-color: #0000aa;
  }
  img {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

This code renders different on each browsers.
My os is macOs Mojave 10.14.6.

[rendering image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzaMa.png)

The redering result by opera is that I was expected.
Why does other browsers render wrong? Is this bug?

Red area is a img tag and image. This must be shrunken by orange are which has 100% width.
However, in not opera, the width of red area(image) is original image width.
I want the width to be shrunken.

Answer (score 0):

```
.main {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;

  color: white;
}

.main-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;

 .text {
    width: 90%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: orange;
  }
}

.image-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 10%;

  .label {
    background-color: #0000aa;
  }
  img {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 
Do you remove the following? I want the code.
.main-flex-container { height: 100% }

I put your adding code and remain the above.
The result is that switching left area(blue, red) and right area(green).
The problem is not solved. I want remove green area.

rendering image
https://imgur.com/a/3CVPhuk

code
https://jsfiddle.net/mitsuru793/n0y6g5qu/37/

Comment: See updated code. You need to set a fixed width on the children of `.main-flex-container`.

Comment: I want to adjust the width from stretched img tag, but is it be available? I must static width. So I put static width, solve it, but it's not dynamic.

Comment: I'm sure there's something I'm missing that I'm just not remembering at the moment. But you can make it dynamic with JS by getting the `innerWidth` of the image and applying it to the `.image-flex-container.`

Comment: I see. I must need javascript. I want to do it by only css, but not be available. I use static width. Thank you very much!